# Published Service not reachable on Docker Swarm

Tags: curl, docker, spring-boot, docker-swarm, docker-network

so I created a service on a docker swarm:

```
docker create service --name my-service --network my-network -p 8761:8761 --replicas 1 my-image
```

It's a Spring Boot application and when looking at stdout of the created docker container the following line is shown:

```
2017-01-19 12:44:48.588  INFO 6 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8761 (http)
```

Indicating the application listens to the proper port.
When running `docker service inspect my-service` it also says the port 8761 is published for this service.

When I then try issue: `curl http://localhost:8761` (on the docker swarm master, the only node in the swarm for now) I run into a timeout. Curling to any other port results in an immediate `Connection Refused` error.

The Spring Boot app works fine when started directly on the machine, there are no hints in the logs, I don't really know where to look next ... anybody a clue here?

Comment: You should `curl` to the manager's ip, not to localhost.

Comment: @AlexanderGeorge thanks, worked. Why can't I use localhost when curling from the manager machine itself?

Comment: I wrote a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should `curl` to the manager's IP**, since it is the node in which your container is running.

You mention in your question that you're running the `curl` command inside the container, but I assume you've done something like `eval $("docker-machine env <manager>")`, which will only allow you to launch containers in the manager. With this you only select the active docker engine to be used.

To actually run a command in the machine you should **ssh into it**, and then you could `curl` to localhost:

`docker-machine ssh <manager> -- curl localhost:8761`

Comment: So `curl` to IP address worked, but I didn't run the `curl to localhost` command in a container, I ran it on the docker swarm master itself, **same machine**.